# Showing that several expressions are/aren't subspaces of $P_3$

Tags: linear-algebra

In order to be a subspace of $P_3$, the set must satisfy the following conditions:

1) $p(x),q(x)\in P_3 \implies (p(x)+q(x))\in P_3$ (Closure under addition)

2) $p(x)\in P_3,\lambda\in \mathbb{R} \implies \lambda p(x)\in P_3$ (Closure under scalar multiplication)

Which of the following are subspaces of $P_3$:

(A) All polynomials $p(x)$ in $P_3$ which have either a local maximum or a local minimum at $x = 0$.

(B) All polynomials $p(x)$ in $P_3$ for which $p(1)$ is a rational number.

(C) All polynomials $p(x)$ in $P_3$ for which $p(1) = p(-1)$.

(D) All polynomials $p(x)$ in $P_3$ for which $p(0) = 0$.

(E) All polynomials $p(x)$ in $P_3$ for which $\int^1_{-1}p(x) dx=0$.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: Changed $x,y$ to $p(x),p(y)$

Comment: Where are you having problems? Why don't you start from definition? Start with $D$, it seems the easiest, and work with the confidence of that question.

Comment: The issue I'm having is that (even with $D$), the only information I'm given in the question is a single point. Would I just prove that any 3rd degree polynomial passing through the origin is a subspace?

Let $p(x) = {a_1}x^3+{b_1}x^2+{c_1}x+{d_1}$ 
Let $q(x) = {a_2}x^3+{b_2}x^2+{c_2}x+{d_2}$

$p(x)+q(x)=(a_1+a_2)x^3+(b_1+b_2)x^2+(c_1+c_2)x+(d_1+d_2)$, which satisfies condition 1. 
Condition 2 is just a matter of changing the co-efficients out the front also. 

Is this on the right track? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. For $D$, you just substitute $x=0$ and see that equality follows. The rest are similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of exercises has always the same resolution pattern. For each statement, you pick two polynomials $p $ and $q $ that satisfy the conditions, and you try to check if it **must** be true that  $p + q $ also satisfies such condition. Then you pick some scalar $\alpha $ and you try to see if $\alpha p $ also satisfies such condition. That is how you do it.

You may also want to remember that there is one other condition for a subspace: it must contain the null vector, $0$.

Comment: So part A would look something like


Let $p(x) = x(a_1 x^2 + b_1 x + c_1)$
$q(x) = x(a_2 x^2 + b_2 x + c_2)$


And then is it a matter of adding the two together, and factorising to get a form that shows it is still in $P_3$?

Comment: @ElijahMoore yes, but note that for A) you know that your polynomials have a local maximum/minima for $x=0$ so you will have to check that, if $p $ has local extrema and $q $ has local extrema, then $p+q $ also has local extrema. To prove that you may want to consider that if a function is differentiable and has extrema on a point, then its derivative is 0 on that point.

Comment: I feel like it needs to be done in general form, but it makes it difficult for E). If we choose (for part E) $\int^1_{-1} ax^2 dx=0$ as our function, how do we know this holds for all $p(x)$ in $P_3$?

Comment: @ElijahMoore you don't choose that function. You pick $p $ and $q $ such that $\int^1_{-1} p = 0$ and $\int^1_{-1} q = 0$. Now you have to show (if) $\int^1_{-1} (p+q) = 0$ and (if) $\int^1_{-1} \alpha p = 0$. This can be done with the properties of integrals

Comment: Ah! Of course! One last question, is (C) implying there is a double root at $p(0)$; is this the only way $p(1)=p(-1)$?

Comment: @ElijahMoore nope that is not the only way. The polynomial $x(x+1)(x-1) $ is 0 both on 1 and -1 and has no double root

Comment: So this implies there is a stationary point at $p(0)$, and that the graph between $[p(-1),p(1)]$ is symmetric about the line $y=p(0)$? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @ElijahMoore not necessarily. If you mess around with the value of $a $ in $(x-a)(x-1)(x+1) $ you can see all kinds of graphs that are not symmetric and where 0 is no stationary point.

Answer (score 0):

c is a subspace of p3 
.if you have any x and y belonging to p3. x+y=z the close in addiction would steel be true.

and the multiplicationas helds k*p(1)=k*p(-1
)

B doesnt belong.if you multily by square root of two the final polymonial will not belong to p3

D belongs. o+o=o ,k*0=0

for e.you may considerer the general formula of plymonyals 
$a*(x^3)+b*(x^2)+c*x+d$

you and integer.
$a*(x^4)/4+b*(x^3)/3+c*(x^2)/2+d*x$

and you may calculate in -1 and 1 the results.

$0=a/4 + b/3 +C/2 +d -a/4 +b/3 -c/2 +d ==b/3 +d$
if you multiply by any constant you have 0 ,if uou sum with aother plymonial you got the same

Comment: The constant function has local minima and local maxima in every point so that is not enough to decide that a) is not a subspace